# Gitlab Cloud run deploy successfully but Job failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab

Im having an issue with my CI/CD pipeline ,
its successfully deployed to GCP cloud run but on Gitlab dashboard the status is failed.

I tried to replace images to some other docker images but it fails as well .

```
 # File: .gitlab-ci.yml
image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine
deploy_int:
  stage: deploy
  environment: integration
  only:
  - integration    # This pipeline stage will run on this branch alone
  script:
    - echo $GCP_SERVICE_KEY > gcloud-service-key.json # Google Cloud service accounts
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcloud-service-key.json
    - gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
    - gcloud builds submit . --config=cloudbuild_int.yaml




# File: cloudbuild_int.yaml
steps:
    # build the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build','--build-arg','APP_ENV=int' , '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/tpdropd-int-front', '.' ]
    # push the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/tpdropd-int-front']
    # deploy to Cloud Run
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ['run', 'deploy', 'tpd-front', '--image', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/tpdropd-int-front', '--region', 'us-central1', '--platform', 'managed', '--allow-unauthenticated']
```

gitlab build output :

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) 
The build is running, and logs are being written to the default logs bucket.
This tool can only stream logs if you are Viewer/Owner of the project and, if applicable, allowed by your VPC-SC security policy.
The default logs bucket is always outside any VPC-SC security perimeter.
If you want your logs saved inside your VPC-SC perimeter, use your own bucket.
See https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you add your GitLab CI/CD Job output? Or otherwise explain what you mean by "failed"?

Comment: Is there a timeout on your Gitlab step? What are the gitlab error message about the fail?

Comment: ive added the gtlab output

Comment: @AdamMarshall  "failed"  is the status of the of the CI/CD workflow.

Comment: @MIkCode - It looks like the gcloud command is returning an error state, even though it's actually completing, based on the `ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) ` at the top of your build output. GitLab will assume the job has failed if the return code from the command is different than 0 - in this case the exit code is 1 (per the last note in your build output).  You either need to figure out why the submit code is returning 0, or you can add an " || true" on the end of your command to ignore the error completely. I'd strongly recommend the first option!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fix it by using:

```
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

in cloudbuild.yaml

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: It appears that after executing the build, the GCP build tries to store the logs in gcloud storage, however, the permissions are insufficient. So by logging only in the console, the gcloud storage error is not thrown. @Tyler2P https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs#store-default-bucket

Comment: how can I fix if I don't use cloudbuild.yaml file?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me: Use `--suppress-logs`

```
gcloud builds submit --suppress-logs --tag=<my-tag>
```

Comment: I tried but it still error and stop build

Answer (score 3):

To fix the issue, you just need to create a bucket in your project (by default - without public access) and add the role 'Store Admin' to your user or service account via https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam

After that, you can refer the new bucket into the `gcloud builds submit` via parameter `--gcs-log-dir gs://YOUR_NEW_BUCKET_NAME_HERE` like this:

```
gcloud builds submit --gcs-log-dir gs://YOUR_NEW_BUCKET_NAME_HERE ...(other parameters here)
```

We need a new bucket because the default bucket for logs is a global (cross-projects). That's why it has specific security requirements to access it especially from outside the Google Cloud, like GitLab, Azure DevOps ant etc via service accounts.

(Moreover, in this case you no need to turn off logging via `--suppress-logs`)

Answer (score 2):

there you can use this work around :

Fix it by giving the Viewer role to the service account running this but this feels like giving too much permission to such a role.

Answer (score 2):

To me worked the `options` solution as mentioned for @Kevin. Just add the parameter as mentioned before in the `cloudbuild.yml` file.

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/myproject/myimage', '.']
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

Answer (score 1):

Kevin's answer worked like a magic for me, since I am not able to comment, I am writing this new answer.

Initially I was facing the same issue where inspite of gcloud build submit command passed , my gitlab CI was failing.
[image: GITLAB CI PUTPUT]

Below is the cloudbuild.yaml file where I add the option logging as Kevin suggested.

steps:

- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud

  entrypoint: 'bash'

  args: ['run_query.sh', '${_SCRIPT_NAME}']

options:
logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY

Check this document for details: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#options

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).